# PHP SOAP Complex Array Handing

Tags: php, arrays, soap, complextype

Seems PHP does not handle complex array properly. Using PHP 5.

WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:tns="urn:CostQueryServicewsdl" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="CostQueryService"
    targetNamespace="urn:CostQueryServicewsdl">
    <wsdl:types xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="urn:CostQueryServicewsdl">
            <xsd:complexType name="WsdService_QueryCostParams">
                <xsd:all>
                    <xsd:element name="date_from" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="date_to" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="hotel_id_array" type="soap-enc:Array" />
                </xsd:all>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="WsdService_CostHotelArray">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        name="WsdService_CostHotel" type="tns:WsdService_CostHotel"
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="WsdService_CostHotel">
                <xsd:all>
                    <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="reserv_policy" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="cancel_policy" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="category_array"
                        type="tns:WsdService_CostHotelCategoryArray" />
                    <xsd:element name="btype_value" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:all>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="WsdService_CostHotelCategoryArray">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        name="WsdService_CostHotelCategory" type="tns:WsdService_CostHotelCategory"
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="WsdService_CostHotelCategory">
                <xsd:all>
                    <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:all>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        name="queryCostRowsRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="params" type="tns:WsdService_QueryCostParams" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        name="queryCostRowsResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="return" type="tns:WsdService_CostHotelArray" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        name="testEchoRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="value" type="xsd:string" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        name="testEchoResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="return" type="xsd:string" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        name="CostQueryServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="queryCostRows">
            <wsdl:documentation></wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:queryCostRowsRequest" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:queryCostRowsResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="testEcho">
            <wsdl:documentation></wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:testEchoRequest" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:testEchoResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        name="CostQueryServiceBinding" type="tns:CostQueryServicePortType">
        <soap:binding xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
            style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="queryCostRows">
            <soap:operation xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                soapAction="urn:CostQueryServicewsdl#queryCostRows" style="rpc" />
            <wsdl:input xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
                <soap:body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                    use="encoded" namespace="urn:CostQueryServicewsdl" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
                <soap:body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                    use="encoded" namespace="urn:CostQueryServicewsdl" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="testEcho">
            <soap:operation xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                soapAction="urn:CostQueryServicewsdl#testEcho" style="rpc" />
            <wsdl:input xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
                <soap:body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                    use="encoded" namespace="urn:CostQueryServicewsdl" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
                <soap:body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                    use="encoded" namespace="urn:CostQueryServicewsdl" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        name="CostQueryServiceService">
        <wsdl:port xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
            name="CostQueryServicePort" binding="tns:CostQueryServiceBinding">
            <soap:address xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                location="http://hs.localhost:8080/wsd_server/service.php?CostQueryService" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</definitions>
```

PHP

```
$options['classmap'] = array('WsdService_QueryCostParams'=>'WsdService_QueryCostParams', 'WsdService_CostHotel'=>'WsdService_CostHotel');
$server = new SoapServer($url . "?" . $classname.'.wsdl', $options);
$server->setClass($classname);
$server->handle();
```

Output dump of SoapClient

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
    'WsdService_CostHotel' => 
    array (
    0 => 
    WsdService_CostHotel::__set_state(array(
       'id' => 'HKG001',
       'day_cell_array' => 
      array (
      ),
       'reserv_policy' => NULL,
       'cancel_policy' => NULL,
       'category_array' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
      )),
       'btype_value' => NULL,
    )),
    1 => 
    WsdService_CostHotel::__set_state(array(
       'id' => 'HKG002',
       'day_cell_array' => 
      array (
      ),
       'reserv_policy' => NULL,
       'cancel_policy' => NULL,
       'category_array' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'WsdService_CostHotelCategory' => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'value' => 'STANDARD',
           'name' => 'Standard',
        )),
      )),
       'btype_value' => NULL,
    )),
  ),
))
```

What I would expect is an array without the extra array around the actural data.

Comment: Please state your question.